# right way to handle time between javascript and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime, time

When retrieving records via Ajax, I only want the records updated after previous request, instead of all records. I know the query should look like:

```
Post.where("updated_at >= ?", last_requested_at)
```

The problem is, `last_requested_at` has to been stored in a Javascript variable, and passed as HTTP query string.

How to encode/decode time between Javascript and Rails? Do I have to worry about time zone?

Comment: Is the previous request process intensive? If not I would go with RobG's solution, otherwise you could have a race condition.

Comment: I don't think there is any race condition. The javascript only read data, not write.

Comment: If the write process hasn't been completed then the read will not include the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is to send all times as UTC time values.

Javascript date objects are based on a UTC time value that is milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, UNIX time values are usually seconds since the same epoch so you just convert ms to seconds by dividing or multiplying by 1,000 as appropriate (or just trim the last three digits or concatenate "000") and you're done.

So to create a javascript date object from a UNIX time value:

```
var date = new Date(UNIXTimevalue * 1000);
```

and back the other way:

```
var UTCTimevalue = date.getTime() / 1000 | 0;
```

The client will deal with time zone offset based on system settings, so as long as they're correct, you're good to go.